# Finding an orientable surface with a given boundary

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm going over the problems [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-b-flux-and-the-divergence-theorem/problem-set-11/MIT18_02SC_SupProb6.pdf), and I'm currently stuck on 6G-3. Intuitively, I try extend the curve $C$ to a short cylinder and try to pull it out where the two loops meet. However, I find this very hard to visualise. Is this a well known problem? If not, could I get some further advice on how to find this surface?
Thanks!

Comment: Start filling in $C$ with a flat disk and then add a tube with a handle to go around one half of the eyeglass.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Oh I see, you're basically thickening up one half of the knot, right?

Comment: yes. ..........